# Jquery fixed size

Tags: jquery, css

I try to fix background and image size and have a conflict with JQuery.
I practice here: http://jsfiddle.net/CyberTramp/uZXQu/

The problem is background-image & div should have a same size like browser resolution "always be in center", my original image width 1500 px

What I have:

CSS

```
.right_circle
{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;   
    background-image: url('http://cloud.graphicleftovers.com/9583/261791/blue-and-orange-circle-globe.jpg'); //original size 500 × 500 must = screen resolution
}
.left_circle
{    position: relative;
    background-image: url('http://www.kidopo.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Circle-mazep.gif');    
}​
```

HTML

```
<body class='left_circle'>
<div class='right_circle'></div>
</body>​
```

JQuery

```
$('html').mousemove(function(e) {
    var page = $('html').width();
    if (page / 2 > e.pageX) {
        $('.right_circle').css('width', page - e.pageX);
    } else {
        $('.right_circle').css('width', page - (e.pageX - (page / 2)) - (page / 2));
    }
});​
```

Comment: is this http://jsfiddle.net/uZXQu/5/, what u are looking for???

Comment: i have big image size and try to make them smaller.
no-repeat it no for this situation. for example if screen have resolution 800x600 my image have 1500 user can see only small part of image. I try to fix it deference way and have a problem with jquery

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is background-image & div should have a same size like
>   browser resolution "always be in center"

Add the following CSS:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Also try to re-organise your styles a little to only specify shared styles ones.

Complete CSS:

```
.right_circle, .left_circle{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%
}

.right_circle{ 
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url('http://cloud.graphicleftovers.com/9583/261791/blue-and-orange-circle-globe.jpg');  
}

.left_circle{    
    background-image: url('http://www.kidopo.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Circle-mazep.gif');
}​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/NT8PU/) - background-image & div have a same size as browser and are centred

Comment: I would guess as CyberTramp is using circles it might be better to use `background-size: contain;` rather than `100% 100%` - could be totally off however ;)

Comment: Applying `background-size: contains;` re-sets the size and the circle does not fill the browser window. As far as I could tell that was one of the requirements. I could be wrong though as requirements are not perfectly clear and if that is not the case, `contains` sounds perfectly fine.

Comment: @CyberTramp: Could you let me know if this is what you were looking for and if not, feel free to add what needs to change and I will update the answer.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I'm not sure if that's a typo but it should be `background-size: contain;` - and in my tests using your code but switching in `contain` instead keeps the aspect ratio of the circles *(rather than stretching them to fit)*. But hey CyberTramp seems happy so alls good :)

Comment: @pebbl: I know. But `stretching to fit` is what OP wanted as far as I could tell. But you are correct if OP wants to keep the aspec-ratio of the circle, then `background-size: contain;` should be used instead.

Comment: @CyperTramp: If you feel this answer has helped solve your issue, feel free to accept the answer by selecting the tick mark to the left of the answer just below the vote buttons. It also indicates to future users who experience similar issue what worked for you.